# What is the difference between identifier and macro?

Tags: c++, data-structures, macros, identifier, preprocessor

When we write a preprocessor directive such as:

```
#define PI 3.1416    
// Is PI is a macro or an identifier and how do we distinguish
// one from another?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `PI` is both a macro and an identifier. "Identifier" is roughly speaking a formal term for the syntax that specifies a name. Macros, functions, namespaces, types, variables all have names, and all those names are specified using identifiers. It should be clear from context whether `PI` is meant as the macro or as the identifier:

> The above defines `PI` as `3.1416`.

Here, it is used to refer to the macro.

> The `PI` following the `#define` specifies the name of the macro.

Here, it is used to refer to the identifier: it is used to refer to the two characters in the source code that specify the macro name.

Comment: What if I write #define PI       what would the PI called?

Comment: @J.Smith The answer to that is exactly the same for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not accurate.

Normatively, an identifier (as a preprocessing token) introduced by a `#define` preprocessing directive is a *macro name*. This is not identical to the macro itself.

Identifiers of preprocessing tokens are transformed to tokens after the preprocessing phases during translation. There are two kinds of tokens look exactly like identifiers of preprocessing token, namely, identifiers and keywords. Keywords are defined by the syntactic rules of the language, and they are never identifiers after the transformation. Note that an identifier of token is not the same to an identifier of preprocessing token.

In the given example, the preprocessing token `PI` will be transformed to the the token `3.1416`. This is neither an identifier nor a keyword (in C, a constant; in C++, a literal). Conceptually, the original preprocessing token does not exist in the translation phases after the transformation. Thus, it is differentiate from an identifier of token after the transformation.